# Open socket in thread and return whole socket?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

maybe someone can tell me how to do this.

I currently have an Android app that sends a short message via bluetooth (createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord) when I select a data-record and hit "Send". The code looks like this

```
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        if(mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            mmSocket.close();
        }
        mmSocket.connect();
        OutputStream mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmOutputStream.write(fullMsg.getBytes());
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
```

This works but is somehow unreliable. mmSocket.connect() fails at least 50% of the time with a timeout and I don't think that the other end of the bluetooth connection is the problem.

So I'd like to try to establish the connection as soon as the app is started (or as soon as the other endpoint - already paired - is visible) but I do not want my app to freez when I run the .connect. So imo I'd have to run the bluetooth socket creating in a thread (should no be a problem) and I'd have to return the mmSocket connection in order to use it later on. Is this the correct approach and if so - how could I return the mmSocket object from the tread without waiting for the thread in the main process.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an static field in your class with the socket and acess it from the main thread